# Почему не отображаются значения в инпуте?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, веб-программирование

Вроде, всё делаю верно. В консоле всё норм считает, но почему-то значение не отображается в самом инпуте.

[Ссылка](https://playcode.io/294630?tabs=script.js&output) на весь код

```js
var counts = $('input[type="number"]')
var total = 0;
for (var j = 0; j < counts.length; j++) {
  var product_price = $(counts[j]).attr('data-product_price');
  total += counts[j].value * product_price;
}
$('td.price > span.value').text(total)

function inc(el, v) {
  console.log(13)
  var i = $(el.parentNode).find("input");;
  var max = +$(i).attr('data-max');
  var min = +$(i).attr('data-min');
  i.value = (+i.val() + +v)

  if (!(i.value % min == 0)) {
    i.value = Math.round(i.value / min) * min
  }
  if (+i.value >= max) {
    i.value = max
  } else if (+i.value <= min) {
    i.value = min
  }
  console.log(i.value)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/products/21/sa-1/" id="id_product_order_form" onsubmit="addProductOrder(event, this)">
  <div class="order_block">
    <div class="options">
      <img src="/media/et/products/products/images/eAxQVlK1XaA2.jpg" data-rjs="2">
      <span class="product">sa
              <span class="note">осталось: 1 кг</span>
      </span>
      <span class="price">1.96 uah
              <span class="note">(за 2 кг)</span>
      </span>
      <span class="to_order">заказать
              <span class="note">(минимум: 2 кг)</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="numerator">
      <input type="number" name="21-product_amount" value="2" min="2" max="2" id="id_21-product_amount" step="2" data-delivery_cost="0" data-product_price="1.96" onkeyup="updateAmount(event, this);" onchange="updateAmount(event, this);" class="field" data-min="2"
        data-max="12">
      <span class="measure">кг</span>
      <button type="button" class="minus" onclick="inc(this, -2)">
              <span class="flaticon-minus-sign-of-a-line-in-horizontal-position"></span>
            </button>
      <button type="button" class="plus" onclick="inc(this, 2)">
              <span class="flaticon-add"></span>
            </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <table class="results">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Суммарно:</td>
        <td class="price">
          <span class="value" id="id_form_amount_all">3.92</span> uah
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Итого к оплате:</td>
        <td class="price">
          <span class="value" id="id_form_result">3.00</span> uah
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="links">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="ThTl5t0UmyuMMo7Z3k1pJ9xnBoncAnAHn6lw0HCHiMSL36Y162UkVh0iE07dYv1F">

    <a href="#" class="add_to_cart" data-slug="21" data-price="1.96">
      <input class="btn btn-danger" id="make_an_order" data-price="1.96" type="submit" value="В корзину"></a>
    <!-- <input type="submit" id="make_an_order"
               value="заказать"> -->
  </div>
</form>

<div id="spec">

  <span class="sp_p">9</span>
  <span class="sp_n">2</span>

  <span class="sp_p">8</span>
  <span class="sp_n">5</span>

</div>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Суммарно:</td>
      <td class="price">
        <span class="value" id="id_form_amount_all">3.92</span> uah
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Итого к оплате:</td>
      <td class="price">
        <span class="value" id="id_form_result">3.00</span> uah
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `i.value = ...` -> `i.val(...)`

Comment: @Igor точно, спасибо...

Comment: @Igor подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не работает `counts.on('change', function() {` ?

Comment: при изменении значения в инпуте с клавиатуры

Comment: Событие `"change"` срабатывает при уходе фокуса с элемента `input`. Используйте `counts.on('input', function() {`

Comment: @Igor ещё раз Спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i.value = ...` -> `i.val(...)`

`value` - свойство DOM-элемента,
`val()` - метод объекта-обертки jQuery

---

Событие `"change"` срабатывает при уходе фокуса с элемента `input`.

Используйте `counts.on('input', function() {`.